# Архивация в Rar C#

Tags: c#, rar

Есть список файлов, как архивировать их в rar, и получить строку, где находится архив с этими файлами.

Comment: Вы уверены, что `rar` это хороший вариант? Это закрытый формат, лицензированный формат. Из-за чего вам надо либо 1. Тащить с собой `Rar.exe` (который в папке с WinRar) и вызывать его с аргументами. 2. Использовать сторонние библиотеки (например `SharpCompress`, но не помню, умеет ли она создавать, распаковывать точно умеет). В любом случае, я бы советовал вам использовать .Zip, в C# есть встроенные для него механизмы по созданию.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ,  к сожалению мне нужен rar файл(

Comment: Используйте zip. RAR - лицензированный формат, поэтому только внешним упаковщиком через консольные команды можно паковать.

Comment: Вызывайте архиватор RAR с параметрами и ему же и передавайте где должен будет лежать файл. Формат проприетарный, без отдельно установленной программы WinRAR вы архив не запакуете.